ClassNotFoundException in TwinColSelect for Vaadin
I upgraded a system (which was built a few years ago by another developer) from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 23.5.4. I then also had to upgrade the dependency for twincolselect (with groupId org.vaadin.tatu) to the latest version, 3.2.0. But this exception then comes:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.flow.component.html.NativeLabel TwinColSelect
at org.vaadin.tatu.TwinColSelect.<init>(TwinColSelect.java:146)

It comes when the TwinColSelect is created in our code:
databasesSelect = new TwinColSelect<>();

org.vaadin.tatu.TwinColSelect is imported and used. How can this be solved?

Well, check if that class has been removed or not, if so, check in which version, and see if  a replacement has been proposed. For v23 of Vaadin I find nothing about that class in the Vaadin docs (https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/ ) I do find it for Vaadin 14

2.X.X (2.7.0 is the latest) is the correct version for Vaadin 23.  The version you are using is for Vaadin 24.
TwinColSelect Vaadin Add-on
Vaadin 24+
Vaadin 23 in 2.7.0
Vaadin 21 in 2.0.0
Vaadin 14 in 1.9.1


Probably you need another dependency.
Just to compile and execute your line:
var databasesSelect = new TwinColSelect<>();

I had to add:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.tatu</groupId>
    <artifactId>twincolselect</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</dependency>

.

The class missing is a UI class from the package org.vaadin
representing basically a HTML element.  I'd be highly suspicious IF
adding spring-data (org.springframework.data) dependencies actually
fixes the problem.

right, the spring dependency is for another class, however both are mandatory. It looks the twincoselect 3.2.0 is not being properly assigned
